# Invalid email headers using WordPress wp_mail()

Tags: php, wordpress, mime-types, email-notifications, email-headers

I get an invalid header when I try to send an email using `WP Mail SMTP`, the test emails work fine. It has been working perfectly for months but from 25.01. it is not working.

My code:

```
 $headers = "From: $email\n;";
 $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
 $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";
 if (wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments)) {
   echo "<h3 style='color:green; text-align: center;'>Email sent!</h3>";
  }
```

**Error thrown:** *invalid_parameter: Invalid headers*

Comment: Why are you using windows new lines and linux new lines? It also looks like the headers can just be an array with no need to worry about the new lines. So something like `$headers[] = "From: $email"; ...etc` would probably be best

Comment: FYI: `$headers = "From: $email\n;";` - that is probably a bad idea; see https://stackoverflow.com/q/24644436/1427878, section titled "Don't use a faux `From:` sender"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the default character encoding for [`wp_mail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/) is UTF-8, you don't need `charset=UTF-8` and also, the Mime version is not needed.

So assuming that all other variables are correctly defined, try to use the following instead:

```php
$headers  = "Content-Type: text/html;\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $email;\r\n";

if ( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ) ) {
    echo '<h3 style="color:green; text-align:center;">Email sent!</h3>';
}
```

Tested and works in last WordPress version.

I have removed `$attachments` argument… If you are using it, you can define it back.